# Can one initialize a set by copying?

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::vector<std::set<int>> m;
m[0].insert(0);
m[0].insert(1);
std::set<int> n = m[0]; // is this allowed?
for(std::set<int>::iterator iter = n.begin(); iter < n.end(); iter++)  // error in this line, "<" not defined.
```

Can I initialize a set by direct copying? There is an error in the last line.

Comment: What happened when it was tried? Was there an error? A warning? Did it just 'not work' (and if not, why not)? What does the documentation (for std::set) say that may indicate one way or the other?

Comment: I think you want to use `iter!=n.end();` instead.

Comment: How would you loop over a set that has _not_ been copied from a set that is container inside a vector?

Comment: Use `++iter` instead of `iter++`...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I initialize a set by direct copying?

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set):

> Constructs new container from a variety of data sources and optionally using user supplied allocator alloc or comparison function object comp.
> ...
>   3) **Copy constructor. Constructs the container with the copy of the contents of other.** If alloc is not provided, allocator is obtained by calling std::allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator()).
>   ...

The problem in your code: You define a vector without any elements inside it, and try to change the element in place 0.
Two solutions:

```
// Solution 1
std::vector<std::set<int>> m(1); // Define vector with one element

// Solution 2
std::vector<std::set<int>> m;
m.push_back(std::set<int>()); // Add new element to the vector with push_back
m.emplace_back(); // Add new element to the vector with emplace_back (recommended)
```

EDIT:

for the last line change the `<` with `!=`:

```
for(std::set<int>::iterator iter = n.begin(); iter != n.end(); iter++)
```

Comment: Your quote about copy assignment is wrong. The code in question does not(!) call the copy assignment nor the move assignment operator. The `=` sign makes one believe so, but since the expression is an initialization, we encounter copy initialization: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Answer (score 0):

- > Can I initialize a set by direct copying?

yes

- > There is an error in the last line

The forloop as written uses the "<" operator to compare if `iter` is still smaller than the end iterator from the set. But the iterator does not have a "<" operator defined. That causes the error message. Use `!=` instead.

- Additionally, your vector does not hold an element. so m[0] is accessing out of bounds. Put an element in first!